# Level Order Traversal BST Code

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I was wondering if someone can review my code for level order traversal in a BST. I am suppose to have `[[3],[9,20],[15,7]]` but instead I get `[[3],[9],[20],[15],[7]]` I know I need an outer while loop but, not sure how to construct it.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

import queue
class Solution(object):
    def levelOrder(self, root):
        L = queue.Queue()
        local = []
        L.put(root)
        while not L.empty():
            node = L.get()
            local.append([node.val])
            if(node.left):
                L.put(node.left)
            if(node.right):
                L.put(node.right)
        return local
```